# How to get view as an object into an action helper

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-view

I have a custom Action Helper that is working fine.
It's generating a dynamic login box if user is not logged in, and if he is, it is generating a menu.

But here I have a problem. 
I want to generate that menu from a small view that's called user_menu.phtml

How I can get that view into my view helper, and assign it to an object?

Ok, some update, sorry for being stupid, actualy I have Action Helper:

I'm sorry If I was specific enough while writing my initial question.

So I have a Action helper in: library/Hlp/Action/Helper
That helper renders a form, if user is not loged inn.

Here is my Helper method, that does that job:

```
public function preDispatch() 
{
    $view = $this->getView();

    $identity = Zend_Auth::getInstance()->getIdentity();

    $session = new Zend_Session_Namespace('users_session');
    $user_id = $session->idd;

    if( !empty($identity) ) {
        $userModel = new Application_Model_Vartotojai();
        $user_email = $userModel->geUserRowBy('id', $user_id);
        $user_email = $user_email['email'];

        $view->login_meniu = $identity.' - 
    [id:'.$user_id.']<br />['.$user_email.'] <br/>
    <a href="/authentication/logout">Log OUt</a>';
    //here I would like to read view file to an object or some other variable
    //if posible to an object si I would be able to inject some values

    } else {        
        $form = new Application_Form_LoginForm();
        $view->login_meniu = $form;
        $view->register_link = '<br /><a href="/users/register">Register</a>';
        //here I would like to read view file to an object or some other variable
    //if posible to an object si I would be able to inject some values
    }
```

Additionaly to that form I want to add some links, or other HTML content, that would br stored in a view file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All you have to do is to extend the [Zend_View_Helper_Abstract](http://framework.zend.com/apidoc/1.7/Zend_View/Helper/Zend_View_Helper_Abstract.html) class. Then you have the view object stored in the public property `$view`.

By using that object you could render your file with

```
return $this->view->partial('user_menu.phtml');
```

**Update**

Since you've updated your question I will update my answer leaving the previous answer because it's still valid for your previous question.

In your case you already have the `$view` object, to do what you're asking for in the comments simply use the [partial helper](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.view.helpers.html#zend.view.helpers.initial.partial) attached to the view in this way:

```
$renderedScript = $view->partial('user_menu.phtml', 
    array('id' => $user_id, 'email' => $user_email['email']));
```

By giving an array or an object as second argument to the partial call you can use them as model in your script file. Example:

```
// content of user_menu.phtml
<h1>Login info</h1>
<p>
  [id: <?=$this->user_id?>]<br />
  [<?=$this->email?>] <br/>
  <a href="/authentication/logout">Log Out</a>'
</p>
```

P.s. I've used the [short_tags + the equal sign (=) shorthand](http://it.php.net/manual/en/function.echo.php) for echo in the view script, if you are not using them you should replace with `<?php echo $this->email ?>`

Comment: Thank you Fabio, I think your answer is close to truth, but I still cant get it working. so I have to initialize $view_obj = new Zend_View_Helper_Abstract(); and then how I can specify what view file I want to use?

Comment: @madcatzx you should post your current code in your question to clarify what you need. You already have a view helper, don't you? So in your class extend the `Zend_View_Helper_Abstract` and you're ok.

Answer (score -2):

From the view, you can pass the this to the helper

```
myHelper($this,$otherVars )
```

And then from the helper you can call the other helper

```
myHelper($view, $otherVars){
  $view->otherHelper()
}
```